# How to read & print a file content ( some settings ) inside a makefile target?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I have this config file ( a plain text file ending in .cfg )

```
# The application name
learningErlangTesting

# The node name
mysql_testing
```

Also, I have this Makefile:

```
ok:
    APP=$(shell cat nodes.cfg | sed -n '2p')
    NODE=$(shell cat nodes.cfg | sed -n '5p')
    echo $(APP)
    echo $(NODE)
```

When I run make ok I get

```
APP=learningErlangTesting
NODE=mysql_testing
echo 

echo
```

My variables are empty it seems, I cannot print them, nor use them to build a folder path ( which I intend to do after I'll get my hands of them ).

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks,
Desmond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that each line of a makefile recipe is invoked in a new shell.  So, the first line is invoked in a shell where the shell variable `APP` is set.  Then the shell exits, losing the setting of the shell variable.  Then the next line is run in a different shell, etc.

You have to put all these in one recipe line so they all run in the same shell.

Also, in your echo command you are printing make variables, but you are actually setting shell variables.

Also, it's almost always a bad idea to use make's `shell` function inside a recipe.  In this case it doesn't hurt but it leads to a lot of confusion.

```
ok:
        APP=$$(cat nodes.cfg | sed -n '2p'); \
        NODE=$$(cat nodes.cfg | sed -n '5p'); \
        echo $$APP; \
        echo $$NODE
```

Alternatively, if the config file is a source file (always exists) you can set real make variables, but you have to do it outside of a recipe:

```
APP := $(shell cat nodes.cfg | sed -n '2p')
NODE := $(shell cat nodes.cfg | sed -n '5p')

ok:
        echo $(APP)
        echo $(NODE)
```

Comment: Rescinded a +1, because `cat ... | sed ...` is a travesty.  Fix the OP's stylistic error and omit the UUOC!

Comment: I tried the second version and it works... Can you explain a bit please: what is $$(...). I know $(...) executes something in a subshell but no idea about $$(...). Also is it required to declare variables in make, outside the target? Many thanks, Desmond

Comment: You need to read about makefile syntax.  Makefiles are not shell scripts and makefile syntax is not shell syntax.  `$(...)` in makefiles  doesn't refer to executing things in a subshell, it refers to a variable reference.  The confusing thing about makefiles is that they _contain_ shell scripts: the recipes for rules are shell scripts and use shell syntax.  To escape a dollar sign so it's passed to the shell instead of interpreted by make, you double it, so `$$` expands to a single `$` which can be passed to the shell.  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@MadScientist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27078919/96588) you have the option to create a **shell script** and launch that from a `Makefile` target. That way, you can also simplify the code quite a bit:

```
$ cat Makefile
ok:
        $(shell ./ok.sh)
$ cat ./ok.sh
sed -n '2p' nodes.cfg
sed -n '5p' nodes.cfg
```

Note: you could also put simply `./ok.sh` in the `ok` target, but then you'd need a [shebang line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Choose_Your_Shell), and I'm not aware of an elegant way to ensure that the resulting script uses the *same* shell as the `Makefile`.